# How Innodb Concurrency Tickets working in sorting by mysql?

Tags: mysql-5.7, concurrency

Innodb concurrency tickets how reduced when the sorting performing query running? is tickets applied for sorting or not? If applied how it was calculated by mysql and is there any performance issue occurred when the sorting query scanned lacks of rows?

The working of Innodb concurrency tickets for sorting queries. Performance issue occurred on sorting queries when it takes sort query.